# How can I request (get) and read an xml file using python?

Tags: python, curl, http-headers, python-requests, urllib

I tried requesting an RSS feed on [Treasury Direct](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/TA_WS/securities/announced/rss) using Python.  In the past I've used urllib, or requests libraries to serve this purpose and it's worked fine.  This time however, I continue to get the [406 status error](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7), which I understand is the page's way of telling me it doesn't accept my header details from the request.  I've tried altering it however to no avail.
This is how I've tried

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.treasurydirect.gov/TA_WS/securities/announced/rss'
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response  = requests.get(url, headers = user_agent)
print response.text
```

**Environments:** Python 2.7 and 3.4.
I also tried accessing via curl with the same exact error.

I believe this to be page specific, but can't figure out how to appropriately frame a request to read this page.

I found an API on the page which I can read the same data in json so this issue is now more of a curiosity to me than a true problem.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

**Header Details**

```
{'surrogate-control': 'content="ESI/1.0",no-store', 'content-language': 'en-US', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'x-powered-by': 'Servlet/3.0', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'set-cookie': 'BIGipServerpl_www.treasurydirect.gov_443=3221581322.47873.0000; path=/; Httponly; Secure, TS01598982=016b0e6f4634928e3e7e689fa438848df043a46cb4aa96f235b0190439b1d07550484963354d8ef442c9a3eb647175602535b52f3823e209341b1cba0236e4845955f0cdcf; Path=/', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains', 'keep-alive': 'timeout=10, max=100', 'connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'cache-control': 'no-store', 'date': 'Sun, 23 Apr 2017 04:13:00 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', '$wsep': '', 'content-type': 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `accept` to headers request:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.treasurydirect.gov/TA_WS/securities/announced/rss'
headers = {'accept': 'application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print response.text
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: I just want to share [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) to make further readers understand why you devised the header that way

Comment: Saved me a ton of time.  Cheers.